# Scala: Median UDF on Data Frame Column Partitioned by adjacent Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, median

I have a DataFrame with columns "id", "Month", "Day", "Hour" and "value" I want to group/partition by id, Month and Hour and perform a median on the value column so that I have a daily median per hour for each month. I have a UDF that can calculate the median:

```
def medianCalculator(seq: Seq[Int]): Int = {
  val sortedSeq = seq.sortWith(_ < _)

  if (seq.size % 2 == 1) sortedSeq(sortedSeq.size / 2)
  else {
    val (up, down) = sortedSeq.splitAt(seq.size / 2)
    (up.last + down.head) / 2
  }
}
```

Taken from [here](http://fruzenshtein.com/scala-median-funciton/)

I can apply this to the whole column and get a result using:

```
val output = df.select("value").collect().flatMap(_.toSeq).toSeq.map(_.toString.toInt)
```

However, I am unable to determine a method that partitions by "id", "Month" and "Hour" and returns the median of "value" once grouped/partitioned in a new column.

**EDIT:**

Added "Day" column above and comment about daily median per hour for each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a lot to go on in your question, but here are a couple of lines to point you in the right direction.

```
val medianUDF = udf(medianCalculator)

val output = df
  .groupBy($"id", $"Month", $"Hour")
  .agg(collect_list($"value").as("values"))
  .select($"id", $"Month", $"Hour", medianUDF($"values"))
```

Comment: Thanks Travis, I was looking for a daily median per hour for each month. I've added this missing detail to my question. Your answer gets me the desired result thank you.